# I forgot to checkout branch before making changes

Tags: git, git-branch

I added a new branch to my git repository for a new feature I was adding and forgot to explicitly check it out. I have since changed a lot of files without committing, but I want to be able to commit these changes to the alternate branch, not the master. How can I do this safely?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just checkout the new branch - your uncommitted changes will be carried over to the new branch.  (This isn't allowed if your local changes would affect a file that would be changed by switching branch, but in this case it sounds as if the new branch is at the same position as your last commit, so that won't be a problem.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728962/forgot-to-create-new-branch-how-to-transfer-changes-to-new-branch     Though I'd throw this here for people that are "new user" friendly.  Answers question with a little more detail

Answer (score 22):

```
git stash

git checkout other_branch

git stash pop
```

Ought to do the trick. You can then commit as normal. See also: [git stash manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html)

Comment: It won't hurt, of course, but `git stash` is actually unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I like the extra sense of security this provides. If you've done __way__ too many edits since your last commit and __really__ don't want to lose them, even if you know `git checkout branch` should be okay, it's still comforting to have a contingency plan in case things go south.

Comment: this worked for me and I felt like this was the best way to go.