# Forgot to create new branch. How to transfer changes to new branch

Tags: git, github

this happens to every developer time-to-time.  You start coding a new feature and forget to branch first locally.

So if that happens is there a way I can say hey, transfer these uncommitted (or committed - yea I know those are both two scenarios which I'd like to cover with this) to a new branch for me locally so I don't have to back them out and copy my changes to a new branch to be able to carry on my way?

Comment: If you have committed already, that's where [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) comes in.

Comment: ok thanks.  So I'd rebase what to what though?

Comment: You would have to ask someone else. I'd be scared of rebasing in all but the simplest situations. It's just better that you pay attention to what you're committing to.

Comment: yea agree with you, thanks

Comment: I recently had this issue with Visual studio team explorer. As git bash does not work with stuff checked out from azure devops for us, and nor does source tree, we are forced to use team exporer to do all git work.  I have yet to find a solution to this use case for team exlorer.

Answer (score 37):

If you haven't commited your changes yet, you can switch to a new branch prior to committing.

```
git checkout -b my-new-branch
```

This will create a new branch called `my-new-branch` and immediately check it out.

Comment: I suppose I could switch back to the previous branch and run `git reset HEAD~` to put that back to its state

Comment: @PositiveGuy What are you talking about? My answer is for if you haven't committed yet.

Comment: ah ok thanks, didn't know that.  Right it wasn't obvious to me that uncommitted is not tied to a branch.  The branch can detect there are changes though!  so it's loosely connected?

Comment: I also wanted to find out if you _have_ committed your changes what to do also

Comment: @PositiveGuy Branches do not "detect changes".

Comment: of course they do.  How do you do a git add if they don't detect something changed?  git status?  how does it detect changes?

Comment: @PositiveGuy No. That's not the "branch detecting a change". That's Git examining the branch and seeing if you've modified any files.

Comment: btw just to let people know, this method works as expected. I had done NO COMMITS, but I have worked on the master for a while, then checked out to a new branch, and committed the work, now I have the clean master and a legit branch.

Answer (score 33):

#### If you have not yet committed:

Then there is no harm in switching to a new branch after files have been modified.  Edited, non-committed files (whether staged for commit or not) are always viewed in the context of whatever branch is checked out:

```
git checkout -b mytopicbranch
```

#### If you've already committed:

Following the description: [here](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/06/08/git-d-oh-i-meant-to-create-a-new-branch-first/):

1. Create the branch you wished you had made (but don't switch to it):

```
git branch mytopicbranch
```

It now has all the commits that you wanted to make.

2. Reset the master branch back to before these commits:

```
git reset abc5b0de1 --hard
```

Assuming `abc5b0de1` is the fingerprint of the commit right before you made the accidental commits.

Now you can switch back to `mytopicbranch` as needed.

Comment: I confess I was a lot suspicious about this because VS Code wasn't tracking my 25 commits in the new branch. I even made a hard copy of everything. But your steps worked perfectly. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 13):

Unless you have done any changes that should not enter the feature branch after you have started work on the feature, it's as simple as creating the feature branch and rewinding the erroneously advanced master branch to the last commit that should not be part of the feature branch:

```
MA --- MB --- MC --- FA --- FB --- FC <- master

git checkout -b feature

MA --- MB --- MC --- FA --- FB --- FC <- feature
                                    ^
                                    |
                                  master

git branch -f master MC

MA --- MB --- MC --- FA --- FB --- FC <- feature
               ^
               |
             master
```

If you have actually mixed your commits, you have a much larger problem. In that case, you need to perform a rebase to unmix the commits, so that you can proceed with the steps above:

```
MA --- FA --- MB --- MC --- FB --- FC <- master

git rebase -i MA
#reorder the lines by moving the commit FA down after MC

MA --- MB' --- MC' --- FA' --- FB' --- FC' <- master

#proceed as above
```

Be aware that you are rewriting history with this: If you have already published `FA`, you are in trouble. In that case, others will notice that you screwed up one way or the other, and the correct solution will include significant amounts of communication between humans.

Comment: For people inscure in git: The `MC` mentioned above is the commit identfier "SHA". It looks something like `bab610d` or the longer `bab610d7bdca523f6087cff051f27d039c2e5a58`. Alas the command will be `git branch -f master bab610d`.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a new branch:

   ```
   git branch newfeature
   ```
2. Checkout new branch: (this will not reset your work.)

   ```
   git checkout newfeature
   ```
3. Now commit your work on this new branch:

   ```
   git commit -s
   ```

Comment: If I do that I get
`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting`

Answer (score 3):

Would it not work to stash your changes, create a new branch and then reapply your stash to the new branch?

Comment: ah yea didn't think of that

Comment: An example of how to stash and apply would be helpful.

Comment: git stash is pretty well documented here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: My point is that if you're going to provide an answer, you should include enough detail in the answer that someone doesn't have to go elsewhere to see what you mean. A link is great, but only as a supplement to your answer. The relevant details need to be in your answer.

Comment: The answer `git stash; git stash branch <name>` is literally shorter than either your rhetorical question or your suggestion to look it up.

Answer (score 3):

1. In case you have committed the changes already!

[In the following case you started off with "Hello world" at the very beginning and after a commit your head was at C4, now, you stayed on master and made commits till C0 but forgot to create different branch at C4 itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drxXx.png)

Now in this case what you can do is

-- Make a patch of commits from C3 to C0 so that you would have changes                         made in respective commits saved in files like C3.patch....C0.patch in 
the directory of your repo itself

-- Reset your HEAD to C4

-- And checkout all the unstaged changes so that you can create a new branch

-- And apply those changes back on the newly created branch

Basically you do

```
-- git format-patch HEAD ~ {n} (n is 4 in this case)
-- git reset HEAD~{n} (reached master or parent branch) 
-- git checkout -- .
-- git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
-- git am (or git am *.patch) (which is git apply -r C*.patch in this case)
```

2. In case where you have not committed changes

-- If they are staged, unstage by resetting head to the previous commit where you started of with making these changes

-- Make a patch of these changes so that you have them stored on local repo directory

-- Checkout those changes and make a new branch

-- Apply that created patch to have those changes back on a new branch

Basically you do

```
-- git reset HEAD~1
-- git diff > unstaged_changes.patch
-- git branch -b <new-branch-name>
-- git am unstaged_changes.patch
```