# How to apply multiple patches taken with format-patch in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I had forgotten to take a branch from my branch and done commits on it. So I had to move these commits to the new branch.

After some investigation I have applied this approach

```
-- git format-patch HEAD ~ {n} (n is 4 in this case)
-- git reset HEAD~{n} (reached master or parent branch) 
-- git checkout -- .
-- git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
-- git am (or git am *.patch) (which is git apply -r C*.patch in this case)
```

which is suggested in this question: [git - Forgot to create new branch. How to transfer changes to new branch - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728962/forgot-to-create-new-branch-how-to-transfer-changes-to-new-branch)

I had 3 commits which I wanted to move and oldest one of them was a merge commit and the other ones were core developments of mine. Because of merge commit which had lots of changes and conflicts, when I issued `format-patch`, it has created over 70 patch files which has this convention `0001-mybranch.patch` and `0071-mybranch.patch`.

To apply these patches I have issued `git am (or git am *.patch) (which is git apply -r C*.patch in this case)` which actually only

`$ git am *.patch` only this was run but gives this error:

```
Patch failed at 0004 mybranch
Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

I had just followed the steps, but what is wrong? How can apply all these patches taken by `git format-patch HEAD~3`? Is the problem about order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had forgotten to take a branch from my branch and done commits on it. So I had to move these commits to the new branch.

There is a much easier way to do this than what you've been attempting.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729233/1256452) to [the question you linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44728962/1256452) (but now that you have run `git reset HEAD~{n}`, you need a slightly different approach; see below).

> I had 3 commits which I wanted to move and oldest one of them was a merge commit ...

The `git format-patch` command *cannot* preserve a merge commit.  It simply drops them entirely.  It also produced too many patches.  These, together, are the cause of your problem.

Given that you already ran `git reset HEAD~{n}`, the trick now is to make your new branch point to *last* of the existing commits that you were trying to copy with `git format-patch`.  To do this, start with:

```
git reflog
```

which will print out all of the various `HEAD@{number}` values and hash IDs for the various commits you've made.  Find the *last* commit you accidentally made on the *wrong* branch and grab its hash ID (use your mouse to cut-and-paste it, or write it down, or something, so that you have it handy).  See below for more options.

Then, run:

```
git log <hash-value>
```

using that hash value.  If that looks right—if those are the commits you want—make a branch name to remember them:

```
git branch newbranch <hash-value>
```

If not, try another of those `HEAD@{number}` hash values until you find the right one.

## Long: what's going on here

Internally, Git isn't really about *branch names* at all.  Git is really all about *commits*.  Branch names just help you (and Git) *find* some particular commit.

#### What's in a commit

Every commit in Git holds a full snapshot of every file.  These files are stored, in these commits, in a special, read-only, Git-only, frozen and compressed and de-duplicated format.  This means that because almost every commit just reuses most of the files from some earlier commit(s), the new commits hardly take any space, because the de-duplicated files take *no* space at all and the new and different files are so well compressed.  A later commit that re-uses a totally new file in *this* commit can share this commit's copy, because that copy is frozen for all time.

(None of this is particularly relevant to what you are doing right now, but keep it in mind in the future: the point to all these commits is to let you "go back in time" to previous versions of files, so *commits* save everything forever, or at least, as long as the commit exists.  That makes them read-only, which means that the files that you actually see and work with *aren't* the files in Git!)

Every commit has a unique number.  Rather than being a simple sequential count, though, like "commit #1" then "commit #2" and "commit #3" and so on, the numbers are random-looking *hash IDs*.  They aren't actually random at all: they're cryptographic checksums of the full commit contents.  That way, every Git everywhere will agree that some particular commit gets *that* hash ID, because they all compute the checksum the same way.  Give them the same set of bits that make up the commit, and they get the same commit number for *that* commit.

Besides the saved snapshot, each commit also holds some *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it—a name and email address—when, and why (the log message in the commit).  There is one part of this metadata that is specifically for Git itself, and that is the commit number—the hash ID—of the *previous* commit.

#### Git works backwards

What this means is that we can *draw* the commits, using uppercase letters to stand in for the real hash IDs (though we'll run out of letters quickly, which is why Git uses such big "numbers").  For instance, imagine a repository early on in its history, when it has only three commits in it:

```
A <-B <-C
```

The *last* commit is commit `C`.  Inside commit `C` there is a full snapshot of all of the files, *plus* the commit number—the hash ID—of earlier commit `B`.  Inside commit `B`, Git has stored the hash ID of earlier commit `A`.

Git can look up any commit by its hash ID.  So if we know the hash ID of the *last* commit `C`, Git can look it up for us.  Then Git can use it to find the hash ID of commit `B`, and look that up, and so on.  This lets Git work *backwards*.  That is how Git works: backwards, from the *last* commit, back.

(Commit `A` is the very first commit, so Git deliberately left out the "earlier commit" part, which is how Git knows how to stop going backwards.)

#### Branch names hold the hash ID of the *last* commit

Now, the one problem we—and/or Git—have left at this point is this: **How do we find the hash ID of the *last* commit?**  Git can work backwards from there, but what's a quick way to find the random-looking hash ID of some actual last commit?

This is where *branch names* come in.  A branch name simply holds *one commit hash ID*, and the one that it holds is the *last* one that is in that branch.

Let's make our graph a bit longer, by adding one more commit `D`.  Let's say that the *name* `master` selects commit `C` as the *last* commit, and the *name* `develop` selects commit `D` as the *last* commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

We now have branches!  Commit `D` points back to commit `C`, which points back to `B`, which points back to `A`.  But now `C` is the *last* commit on `master` and `D` is the *last* commit on `develop`.

If we now `git checkout develop` or `git switch develop`, then make a *new* commit, Git *automatically updates the name `develop` to point to our new commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D--E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The name `develop`, which is our *current branch name*—that's why I added `(HEAD)` here—now selects our new commit `E`.  Commit `E` points back to existing commit `D`, which points back to existing commit `C`, and so on.

#### Here's what you did wrong initially

You had some set of branches.  This drawing will probably be inaccurate—you can use `git log --graph`, perhaps in the form of `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, to get a more accurate (but vertical) drawing of your actual commit graph—but is just meant to illustrate what you did:

```
       H   <-- somebranch
      /
...--G
      \
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

You had *intended* to add a new name and use that as your current branch, like this:

```
       H   <-- somebranch, newbranch (HEAD)
      /
...--G
      \
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

Note in this case that two different *names* select the same *last commit*.  This is perfectly normal in Git.  Many commits are on more than one branch at the same time.  In this case, commit `G` is on *all* the branches, and commit `H` is on two branches, while `I-J` are only on one branch.

If you then ran `git merge anotherbranch` you would have gotten this:

```
       H   <-- somebranch
      / \___
...--G      K   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
      \    /
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

You can then go on to make more commits; I'll just make one, `L`, in this illustration:

```
       H   <-- somebranch
      / \___
...--G      K--L   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
      \    /
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

But you forgot to create the new name `newbranch`.  So instead, you were using the name `somebranch` at the time:

```
       H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
      /
...--G
      \
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

You still made commits `K` and `L`, but instead of having Git drag the *new* branch name forward, you had Git drag the *old* branch name forward:

```
       H
      / \___
...--G      K--L   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
      \    /
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

#### Here's how you tried to fix it

To fix this, you used `git format-patch` to attempt to turn commits `K` and `L` into email-able patches that could be used to re-create commits `K` and `L`.  But `git format-patch` *cannot* reproduce a merge commit, so it just left the merge commit out entirely, and because of the merge commit, it included a bunch of commits you didn't mean to include.  So this part didn't really work.

Ignoring the patch files (which we won't use), you then used `git reset` to make the *name* `somebranch` point back to the place it used to point-to.  That did work, and resulted in this:

```
       H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
      / \___
...--G      K--L   ???
      \    /
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

Note that there is now no *name*—no branch name, anyway—that you can use to *find* the *last* commit `L`.  If you had used the answer I linked above, you would have first created the name to remember the hash ID of commit `L`, then reset the name `somebranch`.

#### Here is how you will fix your fix

Fortunately, Git has these things called *reflogs*.  The `HEAD` reflog has in it, somewhere, the hash ID of existing commit `L`.  The problem is, it has in it the hash ID of *every* commit that `HEAD` has named over the last 30 to 90 days or more.  So there's a whole sea of commits, with random-looking hash IDs, in there, when you run `git reflog`.

The commit you want is going to be close to the top of the reflog output, because it was the `HEAD` commit pretty recently (at the time you made it).  You can also look at the commit-message subject lines, as `git reflog` prints those.

Grabbing the hash ID—or the `HEAD@{3}` number, or whatever—with cut-and-paste, you can run `git log` on that, which will show you the specific commit, then its parent, and so on, the way `git log` usually does.  Once you find the correct hash ID, the command:

```
git branch <name> <hash-ID>
```

will create a new name, pointing to the right hash ID:

```
       H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
      / \___
...--G      K--L   <-- newname
      \    /
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

You can then `git checkout newname` to get:

```
       H   <-- somebranch
      / \___
...--G      K--L   <-- newname (HEAD)
      \    /
       I--J   <-- anotherbranch
```

(note how `HEAD` has moved: now we're working with the files from commit `L` instead of those from commit `H`) to make everything look as if you had created the new branch name when you had intended to, rather than after realizing your mistake.